High distortion problem with common source MOSFET amplifier
I am simulating this circuit, it is a MOSFET common-source amplifier biased using the drain-to-gate resistor configuration.  MOSFET parameters are:
VTO = 1.25V, Lambda = 0.005, Kn = 0.065 (A/(V.V)), W/L =1.

Calculations show voltage gain is -21.34, input resistance is low (44762.8 ohms, but if RG increases this can be fixed) and output resistance is just RD // RL. However, the waveform of the Multisim simulation is quite bad, the output voltage is clipped on the negative (low) portion of the cycle:

And the result is total distortion:

I have 2 questions:
Q1: Can the input offset can be eliminated with another resistor in series with input capacitor?
Q2: What is the best way to avoid distortion of the output, should I ensure that VDS is always larger than VGS?
Thank you

Could you write it clearly in first question?
I think your small signal model has jumped to triode region.
VDS should be larger than Vov.
And your drain voltage is so low that it is easy to jump to triode region
When you are designing an amplifier, you should notice power, gain, output swing, speed etc.

The simulated scope image is confusing.  What is the meaning of the numbers such as "1.730V", and "-1.314V" under "Channel A" and "Channel B"?  Where is the zero-volt line on the scope screen?   Please run the simulation again, this time add more waveforms, as follows: 1: the voltage at the drain of the MOSFET.  2. the voltage at the source of the MOSFET.

In this circuit, Vgs=Vds in quiescent. Therefore Vds can only go one Vth down (Vds being lower than one threshold voltage than Vgs) to remain in saturation. To enhance your output voltage range, you can add a resistor from gate to ground to adjust your quiescent drain voltage.
